# Check if combination of fields in Table1 exists in another Table2 (SQL)

Tags: sql, select

I need to check whether a combination of values in my table A exists in the specified corresponding set of columns in a different table, B.

So far, I'm doing this, which doesn't seem very elegant or efficient:

```
select * from table1 where 
colX_table_1 NOT IN (select colX_table_2 from table2) 
and 
colY_table_1 NOT IN (select colY_table_2 from table2)
```

Is there a better/faster way to do this combination check (colX_table_1,colY_table_1) -> (colX_table_2,colY_table_2)?

Comment: What database system do you use? Also, please note that the SELECT that you provided doesn't actually return the tuples from A that don't exist in B - instead it returns the tuples from A that don't have any match for *either* colX_table_1 and colY_table_1 in table2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The query you gave evaluates each field separately:

```
select * from table1 where 
colX_table_1 NOT IN (select colX_table_2 from table2) 
and 
colY_table_1 NOT IN (select colY_table_2 from table2)
```

This is not merely unelegant, as you claim, it is wrong, as it does not enforce combinations. E.g., consider the following tables:

```
table1:
------
colX colY
1    1

table2:
------
colX colY
1    2
2    1
```

According to your post, you are looking for a query that would return the row in table1, since such a combination does not exist in table2. However, in the given query, each part of the `where` clause evaluates to `false`, and the row is not returned.

Instead, in order to check the combination and not each column individually, you could use an `exists` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table2
                   WHERE  table1.colx = table2.colx AND
                          table1.coly = table2.coly)
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the original query was wrong. This gives the right results.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on your data but this worked in my case:

```
select *
from table1 
where colx||coly not in (select colx||coly from table2)
```

This notation is just a string concatenation: `||`